# How does Linux extract the sixth parameter of syscall?

Tags: linux, x86, system-calls

In 32 bit Intel architecture, the mmap2 system call has 6 parameters. The sixth parameter is stored in the `ebp` register. However, right before entering the kernel via sysenter, this happens (in [linux-gate.so.1](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/), the page of code mapped into user processes by the kernel):

```
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
sysenter
```

This means that `ebp` should now have the stack pointer's contents in it instead of the sixth parameter. How does Linux get the parameter right?

Comment: What glibc function is that code from, exactly?  Or is that from single-stepping in a debugger?

Comment: @PeterCordes this comes from the Linux gate, you can read a short explanation here: http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/ . I know it's a little out of date but modern Linux gate code still does the movl %esp, %ebp part.

Comment: Here's the 32-bit `sysenter_target` code: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S?v=3.14#L384  look at the part starting at line 417.

Comment: Ah, I see, it's simply extracted from the stack. If you write up an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That [blog post](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/) you linked in comments has a link [to Linus's post](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/79839), which gave me the clue to the answer:

> Which means that now the kernel can happily trash `%ebp` as part of the
>   sixth argument setup, since system call restarting will re-initialize
>   it to **point to the user-level stack that we need in `%ebp`** because
>   otherwise it gets totally lost.
>
> I'm a disgusting pig, and proud of it to boot.
>
> -- Linus Torvalds

It turns out `sysenter` is *designed* to require user-space to cooperate with the kernel in saving the return address and user-space stack pointer.   (Upon entering the kernel, `%esp` will be the kernel stack.)  It does way less stuff than `int 0x80`, which is why it's way faster.

After entry into the kernel, the kernel has user-space's `%esp` value in `%ebp`, which it needs anyway.  It accesses the 6th param from the user-space stack memory, along with the return address for SYSEXIT.  Immediately after entry, `(%ebp)` holds the 6th syscall param.  (Matching the standard `int 0x80` ABI where user-space puts the 6th parameter there directly.)

From Michael's comment:  "Here's the [32-bit sysenter_target code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S?v=3.14#L384): look at the part starting at line 417"

---

From Intel's instruction reference manual [entry for SYSENTER](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sysenter) (links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki):

> The SYSENTER and SYSEXIT instructions are companion instructions, but
>   they do not constitute a call/return pair. When executing a SYSENTER
>   instruction, the processor does not save state information for the
>   user code (e.g., the instruction pointer), and neither the SYSENTER
>   nor the SYSEXIT instruction supports passing parameters on the stack.
>   To use the SYSENTER and SYSEXIT instructions as companion instructions
>   for transitions between privilege level 3 code and privilege level 0
>   operating system procedures, the following conventions must be
>   followed:
>
> - The segment descriptors for the privilege level 0 code and
>     stack segments and for the privilege level 3 code and stack segments
>     must be contiguous in a descriptor table. This convention allows the
>     processor to compute the segment selectors from the value entered in
>     the SYSENTER_CS_MSR MSR.
> - The fast system call “stub” routines
>     executed by user code (typically in shared libraries or DLLs) must
>     save the required return IP and processor state information if a
>     return to the calling procedure is required. Likewise, the operating
>     system or executive procedures called with SYSENTER instructions must
>     have access to and use this saved return and state information when
>     returning to the user code.

Comment: Your answer is correct but is all over the place. Learning about the relative merits or the spec of sysenter isn't in the scope of this question, and obscures what is relevant. I recommend that you incorporate Michael's comment and link into your answer, and possibly whittle down the irrelevant parts. I'm going to accept it anyway, but I think you'll get more upvotes by keeping the answer concise.

Comment: @nitzanms: As I see it, the mystery is why user-space creates a stack frame.  Once you know that the kernel needs user-space's help to get all the info that needs to be saved, it's easy to understand that some of the info is on the user-space stack, pointed to by `%ebp` on entry into the kernel.  I thought `mov somewhere, (%ebp)` was obvious enough once you know the bigger picture of what's going on, but I'll add it.  If you have any further suggestions, leave a suggested edit.

Comment: Sure thing. I didn't mean to sound like an ass but on a second read I kinda did, so my apologies about that.

Comment: @nitzanms: Thanks, no hard feelings.  I took your comment as saying that some of the stuff I left out because it was too obvious wasn't actually obvious to everyone.  That's a fair point.  But I didn't want to whittle down the other parts, because they're key to understanding why the whole thing is designed this way.  e.g. just answering `mov (%ebp), somewhere` isn't useful, because it begs the question of why user-space stashed %ebp into memory in the first place.